# C# XAML grid Expander

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

kind of new the WPF projects and the xaml is really confusing.

I have a datagrid displaying grouped ListCollectionView and I would like to have a click button so the grouped view can collapse.  It seems to be an easy function to achieve but searched everywhere for the past day there is not a single example to walk through this (maybe it is too easy?)

Here is the code for my XAML

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType = "{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander x:Name="myExpander" IsExpanded="True"
                              Background="LightBlue"
                              Foreground="Black">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

and in the mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
            ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(dt.DefaultView);
        collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Grouping"));

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = collection;
```

Please help.  Thank you all very much.

Comment: Why don't you put your list view directly into an expander control ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to override / set the `GroupStyle`. But your sample code looks pretty ok - so maybe i just dont understand whar your problem is.

```
 <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="true" Header="Yolo">
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Pls add aditional information if it isnt what you are looking to do!